# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum

Running a hashlips script on node js and getting the following error: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined""

It points to these lines:

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    `${buildDir}/json/${_editionCount}.json`,
    JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2)
  );
```

Here:

```
saveMetaDataSingleFile(abstractedIndexes[0]);
          console.log(
            `Created edition: ${abstractedIndexes[0]}, with DNA: ${sha1(
              newDna
            )}`
          );
```

Also here:

```
await Promise.all(loadedElements).then((renderObjectArray) => {
          debugLogs ? console.log("Clearing canvas") : null;
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, format.width, format.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that metadata in the below line is undefined or something that cannot be converted to a JSON string.

JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2)

Your code doesn't show how metadata is generated so I cannot help more.